# Why adding custom SASS variables does not work in Ionic?

Tags: sass, ionic-framework

I setup a new ionic project using the -s option to enable SASS.

Here is a part of my /myproject/scss.ionic.app.scss:

```
...
$positive:                        #2a8000 !default;
$button-font-size:                30px !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";
```

When saving this scss file, I can see in the shell that sass is launched and css is re-built:

```
[00:18:18] Starting 'sass'...
CSS changed:  www/css/ionic.app.css
[00:18:18] Finished 'sass' after 330 ms
CSS changed:  www/css/ionic.app.min.css
```

However, the new css file seems to be exactly the same, whatever I put into the scss file.

Can you explain why?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: stupid question but did you remove the `/*..*/` comment block surrounding this block that exists in the scss file by default, i'm guessing yes, but just checking

Comment: Thanks, but I found the stupid mistake I made :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was pretty stupid...

I didn't pay attention that SASS generates the new css in `www/css/ionic.app.css`
However, the file included in the default ionic index.html is `lib/ionic/css/ionic.css`

The only thing to do is to write
`<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">` in index.html

and remove
`<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I had the same issue, but I found the answer at http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/sass/, using `ionic setup sass` as shown is the video.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this in my project, I had to install gulp first.

```
npm install -g gulp
```