# Ionic create new sass file

Tags: javascript, html, sass, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic framework for my html5 mobile app.

I know I can add custom sass into the ionic.app.scss file under the scss folder and ionic serve or ionic build will compile my sass into css, but if I want to add additional sass files here, for instance ionic.home.scss how do I get these to compile? Do I need to modify the gulp file.

I am basically extending the default [Ionic tabs app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs) app. Here is the structure I was wanting, basically a sass file for each template

```
+-- _gulpfile.js
+-- _scss
|   +-- ionic.app.scss
|   +-- tab-home.scss
|   +-- tab-projects.scss
|   +-- tab-services.scss
+-- _templates
|   +-- tab-home.html
|   +-- tab-projects.html
|   +-- tab-services.html
+-- index.html
```

Here is the gulp file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function() {
  return bower.commands.install()
    .on('log', function(data) {
      gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
    });
});

gulp.task('git-check', function(done) {
  if (!sh.which('git')) {
    console.log(
      '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
      '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download Ionic.',
      '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-scm.com/downloads') + '.',
      '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
    );
    process.exit(1);
  }
  done();
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have just one `ionic.app.scss` and extend it with `@import` in this file.

```
@import "tab-home.scss", "tab-projects.scss", "tab-services.scss";
```

Comment: just for my own reference in a new project I struggled to get ionic.app.scss to compile to ionic.app.css, running ionic setup sass set it all up correctly in the index.html, here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371530/why-adding-custom-sass-variables-does-not-work-in-ionic) to that problem, even though I have had no issue in the past changing the link manually in the index.html

Comment: I tried that, and now gulp is not watching either of the files, I tried to revert it, but it still not watching, any thoughts ?

Comment: don't forget that you need to restart the ionic server (i.e., re-run the gulp task) after adding *.scss files to your project so that gulp can know to watch them

Comment: I am having a similar issue - Altough this solution will work - it still actually doesnt answer the question on how to fix the gulp task.

Comment: The task is not broken, why do you want to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `gulp.src()` in the sass or scss task in your gulp file to something like `gulp.src("_scss/**/*.scss")` the double * means that any subdirectories are included. Also if you dont want to output another css file you need to create partials(just add a `_` to the beginning of your sass file names.

Comment: I tried ("_scss/**/*.scss") but it did not work, it was previously ('./scss/ionic.app.scss')

Comment: Send me your gulp file or just your scss task and ill try to fix it. You probably need to change your gulp.dest() to something like "dist/css/" though

Comment: I added the gulp file to the description above, Thanks

Comment: gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')